# Defining a function for certain values of one parameter

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I want to define function as

```
def log_odds_ratio(counts, word, polarity)
```

in which polarity is either pos or neg, both are dictionaries. My function will consist of different formulas for each case, either pos or neg. How can I continue to define my function? The formulas for log_odds_ratio(counts, word, pos) and log_odds_ratio(counts, word, neg) are different.

edit:

```
import math

def log_odds_ratio(counts, word, polarity):

This function returns the log odds ratio of a term (see previous cell)

Parameters:
counts (dict): the dictionaries 'pos' and 'neg' which count word occurances
word (str): the word you want to get the probability for
polarity (str): wither 'pos' or 'neg'

Returns:
log_odds_ratio (float): log( prob(word|plarity) / P(word|opposity_polarity) )

"""
# Your code goes here
wordsInPolarity = list(counts[polarity].keys()) #Build a list of words
sumCounts = 0


for word in wordsInPolarity:
    if counts[polarity]='pos':
        log_odds_ratio =math.log(get_word_prob(counts, word, 'pos')/get_word_prob(counts, word, 'neg'))
    if word in counts['neg']:
        log_odds_ratio  =math.log(get_word_prob(counts, word, 'neg')/get_word_prob(counts, word, 'pos'))      
return log_odds_ratio 


Do not change
print(log_odds_ratio(counts, "great", "pos")) # should print 1.2755975445193852
print(log_odds_ratio(counts, "the", "neg")) #  should print -0.09155418404114618
print(log_odds_ratio(counts, "wug", "neg")) # should print a very large number
```

Comment: How about an `if`-statement?

Comment: yes, I tried it but could not operationalize successfully.

Comment: Show what you tried (as properly formatted code in the question).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: How can a dictionary be positive or negative...

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it clearer. sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Prune and @Michael Butscher, it's best practice to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with your question. In other words, show people what attempts you have made to solve the problem and why you think you might have failed. Nonetheless, here's something to help you get started.

Use an `if` statement.

```py
def log_odds_ratio(counts, word, polarity):
    if polarity: # polarity is positive
        return log_odds_ratio_pos(counts, words)
    else: # polarity is negative
        return log_odds_ratio_neg(counts, words)
```

Then define functions for each case.

```py
def log_odds_ratio_pos(counts ,words): # formula when polarity is positive
    pass # code goes here

def log_odds_ratio_neg(counts ,words): # formula when polarity is negative
    pass # code goes here
```

Of course, you can simply implement this in one function, but it doesn't hurt to break functions into pieces for better readability and easier debugging.

**EDIT**

You can handle everything in a single function with minimal modifications.

```py
def log_odds_ratio(counts, word, polarity):
    if polarity: # polarity is positive
        pass # formula goes here
    else: # polarity is negative
        pass # formula goes here
```

Comment: thank you. I am new to both here and python, and apparently making a mess while asking questions. hopefully will progress.

that is what makes more sense to me too, but I am doing a homework and our professor apparently wants us to code it in only one function.

Comment: @BronBron I'm new to this community as well, I feel you. Just make sure to post your source code when asking for help. Also, in light of your comment, I have made a small edit to the post.